# CSS only collapsing menu only works in firefox, not webkit browsers, why?

Tags: html, css, list

Got help earlier on how to get this collapsing menu to work. But now all of a sudden the links in it won't work. they just contract the the menu again. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

CSS:

```css
#list, .show {display: none; }
.hide:focus + .show {display: inline; }
.hide:focus { display: none; }
.hide:focus ~ #list { display:block; }
@media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
li.folding {list-style-type:none; margin-left:-20px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="hide">[Link]</a>
<a href="#" class="show">[Link]</a>
<ol id="list">
    <li class="folding"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="folding"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="folding"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 3</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: DO you have any script on this page?

Comment: No nothing more than what's above. This is really strange Hmm...

Comment: There has to be JS involved... Explain us how you are making them collapse please

Comment: `<a>` tags don't have focus (I think), try using `:hover` instead.

Comment: @Salketer: CSS can do this by itself.  The magic is in the `:focus` and the `+`.  Like in: `.hide:focus + .show`.  This means, this rule affects "a `.show` element, that's *next to* a `.hide` element that has focus.  So, when you focus the `[Link]`, the menu is shown.  See: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: When you click on the `<a>` tag within `#list`, `.hide` loses focus.  When `.hide` loses focus, `.show` is set to `display:none`

Comment: Why do you have two `[Link]`s?  Why is one `.hide` and the other `.show`?

Comment: Actually there's not. Check it out in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/GpqSW/ i got the script from: http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/showing-and-hiding-content-with-pure-css3.php

Comment: FYI for all looking at fiddle, you have to use TAB to get it to work, you can't click it and expect results

Comment: @ChrisRockwell OK, any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: One problem I see us, when you focus `.hide`, it opens the menu, but it also hides `.hide`.  With `.hide` hidden, it can't be focused, so the menu cannot be shown.

Comment: @GetGalax: I went to their example page, and it doesn't even work: http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/demo/css-menu-ex1.html  I don't know how you found that but I suggest you find another one.  That one sucks.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ah I see, thank you much for this info, didn't think about it. Then that explains why the links fold when you click them... The element looses focus!

Comment: The solution on the website is more of a sandbox.  I wouldn't use this in the 'real-world' with focus - what if a user wants to use their mouse??

Comment: It should be noted he's using FF16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine as it is..

**[Working JSFiddle. ( IN FIREFOX ONLY ! )](http://jsfiddle.net/W4pGz/)**

The problem is more `browser compatibility`, run the JSFiddle in firefox and it will work as you expect, on chrome and safari it does not work.

The better solution for this (for all browsers), is to use `Javascript/jQuery` to hide and show the menu on click of a button, this will work across all mobiles, tables & browsers consistently with minimal code.

---

#### Update

Here is a quick example of getting this working using `jQuery`. You can see the code is very small, easy to read and extend, and will also work on ALL browsers!

[VIEW THE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AhtWJ/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="toggler">[Link]</a>
<ol id="list">
    <li class="folding"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="folding"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="folding"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 3</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
// When the page is loaded and ready
$(function(){
    // On click of `.toggler` (the <a> with class `.toggler`)
    $('.toggler').click(function(){
        // Toggle the list menu (toggle means if hidden show it, else hide it)
        $('#list').fadeToggle(); // also try.. `slideToggle()`
    });
});
```

The above HTML & Javascript does exactly the same thing, except it will work on all devices!

### [View the JSFiddle - Javascript/jQuery Version](http://jsfiddle.net/AhtWJ/)

Comment: Actually I'm on Firefox (perhaps an old one though) and it doesn't work. But yeah, I should probably try to find a another script...

Comment: I'm on Firefox 16, so i'm guessing im basicly a dinosaur ;)

Comment: @GetGalax: Firefox updates so quickly that 16 is actually from last year (June 2012)!

Comment: Check my update with javascript, it will work on all browsers!

Answer (score 0):

Since clicking another link makes the first one loose focus, the items in the list go back to hiding.

Since the focus loss is always done before executing the click behaviour, the click does not reach the link since it is not under your mouse anymore.